# what is the @ + number means for task name

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-tasks

I found many task names are end up with `@` sign plus a number, please see example below

```
# Provides credentials for Azure Artifacts feeds and external Maven repositories.
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  #inputs:
    #artifactsFeeds: MyFeedInOrg1, MyFeedInOrg2 # Optional
    #mavenServiceConnections: serviceConnection1, serviceConnection2 # Optional
```

What's the purpuse of this `@0` for universal identity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It represents for **task version**.

And this configuration corresponds to the task version selection operation from UI:

[image]

In your scenario, after the pipeline start to run, it will download `MavenAuthenticate` task which version is `0.*`.